# Rails DRY mechanism to render flash messages to JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I have a very basic API in my app which also has an index page to allow testing/demonstrating various API functions.

Due to this index HTML page all the functions should be able to respond in either HTML (which just re-renders the index page with flash messages attached) or JSON (which just sends back a simple status/message object).

Each function currently looks a little like this...

```
def do_stuff

  if params['stuff']

    begin
      Helper.do_stuff params['stuff']
    rescue Exception => ex
      msg = ex.message
      status = 'error'

      flash[:error] = msg
    else
      msg = 'Stuff done'
      status = 'success'

      flash[:success] = msg
    end

  else
    msg = 'No stuff provided'
    status = 'error'

    flash[:error] = msg
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'api/index' }
    format.json do
      render json: {:status => status, :message => msg}
    end
  end
end
```

What would people recommend to DRY this up? It seems it would be good to somehow construct the JSON status object from the flash hash.

I'm thinking either using a Helper or would there be something more elegant by having the logic to parse the flash hash from a JSON layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found just rendering the flash hash directly for the JSON response works well enough...

```
def do_stuff
  if params['stuff']

    begin
      Helper.do_stuff params['stuff']
    rescue Exception => ex
      flash[:error] = msg
    else
      flash[:success] = 'Stuff done'
    end

  else
    flash[:error] = 'No stuff provided'
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :action => 'index' }
    format.json do
      render json: flash
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to call the `to_hash` method on flash before rendering it as json. In some versions of rails, `flash.to_json` doesn't actually return a JSON hash.

```
def do_stuff
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :action => 'index' }
    format.json do
      render json: flash.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```